# Can't resolve all parameters for MyMissingTranslationHandler or Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! DataTransferService

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

As the title states, I get these 2 errors.

```
Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! DataTransferService
```

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyMissingTranslationHandler
```

I tried to fix the `Can't resolve all parameters` error by adding `@Inject` but it led to the `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency` error. I'm not sure what to do and other SO answers have not helped much.

```js
//app.module.ts
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  constructor(
    // @Inject(DataTransferService)private dataTransferService // gives me cyclical dependency error

    // private dataTransferService: DataTransferService // gives me can't resolve all parameters error

    ) {}

  private missingTrans: {[key:string]:string} = {}

  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
      this.missingTrans[params.key] = "missing translation"
      //write translation
      // this.dataTransferService.writeMissingTranslation(this.missingTrans);

      console.log(this.missingTrans)
      return params.key;
  }

  getMissingTrans(){
    return this.missingTrans;
  }

}
```

```
…
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: InitializeContent,
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    },
    AuthGuard,
    DataTransferService,
    AppService,
    GlobalVars,
    // LoginService,
    LoaderService
  ],
…
```

Comment: Can you post `DataTransferService` please? or its constructor dependencies please?

Comment: ```constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private snackbarService: SnackbarService, private dynamicTranslateService: DynamicTranslateService) {  }```